# How to get a pattern returned when a dataframe is compared to single values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I need to compare Pandas Series data to a 2d Array (DataFrame) and return string patterns from it. 
Let's say I have a board with rows and columns which I can generate with this list comprehension:

```
data = [[chr(x)+str(y) for x in range(65,65+4)]for y in range(1,5)]
[['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'],
 ['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'],
 ['A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3'],
 ['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4']]
```

I can create a Pandas Dataframe from it with:

```
df  = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[1,2,3,4], index=["A","B","C","D"])
```

resulting in:

```
    1   2   3   4
A  A1  B1  C1  D1
B  A2  B2  C2  D2
C  A3  B3  C3  D3
D  A4  B4  C4  D4
```

I want now compare a Series against this DataFrame and return a pattern as string.

```
df2 = pd.Series(data=["A1","B2","B3","C4"])
```

When the following series would be compared to the template dataframe, the returned patterns should be columnwise result in:

```
["1000", "0110", "0001"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pd.DataFrame.isin`:

```
ind = df.isin(df2.values).T.astype(int).values
[''.join(map(str, a)) for a in ind[ind.any(1)]]
```

Output:

```
['1000', '0110', '0001']
```

Explanation:

*first line*

- `df.isin(df2.values)` checks if [each element in the df is contained in](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) `df2.values`, i.e. `["A1","B2","B3","C4"]`
- `T` or `transpose()` returns transposed dataframe, since the desired output seemed to be of columnar join, not row-wise.
- `astype(int)` returns bools converted into `0`s and `1`s

*second line*

- `ind[ind.any(1)]` returns rows where at least one element is `True`, or in this case, `1`. (Since you didn't seem to need `0000`)
- `''.join(map(str, a))` returns joined `str` from a row of integers

Answer (score 1):

Just for your convenience, you can also use [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html#pandas.Series.eq) to compare values in each column to the series

```
[''.join(df.reset_index(drop=True)[col].eq(df2).astype(int).values.astype(str)) for col in df.columns]
```

---

```
['1000', '0110', '0001', '0000']
```